# Enable Two Way Data Binding when adding them dynamically to the template in (using innerHtml) Angular 4 +

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg

i'm trying to edit the text from one of the svg textarea via input by using the two way data binding syntax of Angular
im getting the svg content from my server so i have to add it to the html via [innerHtml] and for  and the Angular Interpolation ( {{...}} ) is already in the svg 
Angular is requiring to add `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlValue)` if i add html from the  outside

**when i run the app its bring up my svg but showing the two way data binding syntax as a string {{Name}}** and i'm not able to change the value when im typing in my input 
*`(see image link below how its looks in the browser)`*

any help ?

```js
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { LatterDetails } from 'src/Module/LatterDetailsModule';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css'],
})

export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
public Name = "abc";

   public svgFile;
   constructor() {} 
  

  ngOnInit() {
  this.svgFile =`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"     viewBox="0 0 2400 3300">
    <defs>
      <style>
        .cls-1,
        .cls-2 {
          font-size: 125px;
          text-anchor: middle;
        }
    
        .cls-1 {
          font-family: "AR CARTER";
        }
    
        .cls-2 {
          font-family: "AR JULIAN";
        }
    
        .cls-3 {
          font-size: 200px;
        }
      </style>
    </defs>
    <image id="images" y="27" width="2424" height="3281" xlink:href='https://openclipart.org/download/282853/Border-68-US--Arvin61r58.svg' />
    <text id="_details.Name_" class="cls-1" x="1200" y="2526.002">
      **<tspan x="1200">Name: {{Name}}</tspan>**
    </text>
    <text id="abc_123" data-name="abc 123" class="cls-2" x="1203" y="665.999">
      <tspan x="1203">abc 123</tspan>
    </text> 
    </svg>`;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" [innerHtml]="svgFile | safe: 'html'">
    </div>
        <input [(ngModel)]="Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

[see how its show in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz7UR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
Name: ${Name}</tspan>**
```

Comment: i did try this too but this not works ether it's only sets the value at the first load but its not connected to the input